# When I used Intent post parcelable, I found other extras can't get

Tags: android

[image: This is the code that posts extras]

[image: This is the code that gets extras]

In Android version 6.0.1, it will throw [image: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@77d2617: Unmarshalling unknown type code 3342385 at offset 348]

In other version, will not throw this, but can't get other extras except parcelable. I know the reason. Because  I implements Parcelable and Cloneable. If I only implements Parcelable, it's OK.

Comment: put parceable in intent part

Comment: I  added "-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static ** CREATOR;
}" , but it didn't work.

Comment: Have you implemented 'Parcelable' in your data object? If your data actually is an array, you need to use putParcelableArrayListExtra

Comment: I have implemented 'Parcelable' , and I implemented 'Cloneable'.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent= new Intent(this, that.class);
intent.putExtra("string", parceable value);
intent.putExtra("string", Boolean value);

Intent intent= getIntent();
Boolean bool= intent.getBooleanExtra("string");
var xyz= intent.getParceableExtra("string");
```

Do it this way.

Comment: I can't find the method "putParceableExtra()".

Comment: I edited the code. there in no such function . but you have to put it just like Boolean or some other data type

Comment: I change my code as your answer, but I still can‘t get the  BooleanExtra.~~~~(>_<)~~~~

Comment: Because I implements Parcelable and Cloneable. If I only implements Parcelable, it's OK.

Answer (score 0):

I use Serializable to replace Parcelable, this problem never occur. But I still want to solve it.

```
public class ContactEntity implements Parcelable,Cloneable{
private String contactID;
private String groupID;
private String phone;
private String name;
private String noteName;
private Integer sex;
private Long created;
private Long updated;
private Integer status;
private String orgGuid;
private String createrID;
private Integer ifSync = 0;
private Integer ifRegHx = 0;

private SpannableString phoneSS;

public ContactEntity() {
}

public ContactEntity(JsonNode jsonNode){
    this.contactID = jsonNode.get("id").asText();
    this.groupID = jsonNode.get("groupid").asText();
    this.phone = jsonNode.get("phone").asText();
    this.name = jsonNode.get("name").asText();
    this.noteName = jsonNode.get("remarkname").asText();
    this.sex = jsonNode.get("sex").asInt();
    this.created = jsonNode.get("created").asLong();
    this.updated = jsonNode.get("updated").asLong();
    this.status = jsonNode.get("status").asInt();
    if(jsonNode.has("ifsync")&&jsonNode.has("ifreghx")){
        this.ifSync = jsonNode.get("ifsync").asInt();
        this.ifRegHx = jsonNode.get("ifreghx").asInt();
    }
    this.orgGuid = UserConfig.getInstance().getCompany();
    this.createrID = UserConfig.getInstance().getClientUserId();
}


protected ContactEntity(Parcel in) {
    contactID = in.readString();
    groupID = in.readString();
    phone = in.readString();
    name = in.readString();
    noteName = in.readString();
    sex = in.readInt();
    created = in.readLong();
    updated = in.readLong();
    status = in.readInt();
    orgGuid = in.readString();
    createrID = in.readString();
}

public static final Creator<ContactEntity> CREATOR = new Creator<ContactEntity>() {
    @Override
    public ContactEntity createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new ContactEntity(in);
    }

    @Override
    public ContactEntity[] newArray(int size) {
        return new ContactEntity[size];
    }
};

@Override
public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    return super.clone();
}

public SpannableString getPhoneSS() {
    return phoneSS;
}

public void setPhoneSS(SpannableString phoneSS) {
    this.phoneSS = phoneSS;
}

public String getContactID() {
    return contactID;
}

public void setContactID(String contactID) {
    this.contactID = contactID;
}

public String getGroupID() {
    return groupID;
}

public void setGroupID(String groupID) {
    this.groupID = groupID;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getNoteName() {
    return noteName;
}

public void setNoteName(String noteName) {
    this.noteName = noteName;
}

public Integer getSex() {
    return sex;
}

public void setSex(Integer sex) {
    this.sex = sex;
}

public Long getCreated() {
    return created;
}

public void setCreated(Long created) {
    this.created = created;
}

public Long getUpdated() {
    return updated;
}

public void setUpdated(Long updated) {
    this.updated = updated;
}

public Integer getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(Integer status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getCreaterID() {
    return createrID;
}

public void setCreaterID(String createrID) {
    this.createrID = createrID;
}

public String getOrgGuid() {
    return orgGuid;
}

public void setOrgGuid(String orgGuid) {
    this.orgGuid = orgGuid;
}

public Integer getIfSync() {
    return ifSync;
}

public void setIfSync(Integer ifSync) {
    this.ifSync = ifSync;
}

public Integer getIfRegHx() {
    return ifRegHx;
}

public void setIfRegHx(Integer ifRegHx) {
    this.ifRegHx = ifRegHx;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(contactID);
    dest.writeString(groupID);
    dest.writeString(phone);
    dest.writeString(name);
    dest.writeString(noteName);
    dest.writeInt(sex);
    dest.writeLong(created);
    dest.writeLong(updated);
    dest.writeLong(status);
    dest.writeString(orgGuid);
    dest.writeString(createrID);
    dest.writeInt(ifSync);
    dest.writeInt(ifRegHx);
}


public static class Builder {
    private String contactID;
    private String groupID;
    private String phone;
    private String name;
    private String noteName;
    private Integer sex;
    private Long created;
    private Long updated;
    private Integer status;
    private String orgGuid;
    private String createrID;
    private Integer ifSync;
    private Integer ifRegHx;

    public Builder withAutoID(){
        this.contactID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        return this;
    }

    public Builder buildGroupID(String groupID){
        this.groupID = groupID;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder buildPhone(String phone){
        this.phone = phone;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder buildName(String name){
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder buildNoteName(String noteName){
        this.noteName = noteName;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder buildSex(Integer sex){
        this.sex = sex;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder buildCreated(Long created){
        this.created = created;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder buildUpdated(Long updated){
        this.updated = updated;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder buildStatus(Integer status){
        this.status = status;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder withAutoOrgGuid(){
        this.orgGuid = UserConfig.getInstance().getCompany();
        return this;
    }

    public Builder withAutoCreaterID(){
        this.createrID = UserConfig.getInstance().getClientUserId();
        return this;
    }

    public Builder buildIfSync(int ifSync){
        this.ifSync = ifSync;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder buildIfRegHx(int ifRegHx){
        this.ifRegHx = ifRegHx;
        return this;
    }

    public ContactEntity build(){
        ContactEntity entity = new ContactEntity();
        entity.setContactID(contactID);
        entity.setGroupID(groupID);
        entity.setPhone(phone);
        entity.setName(name);
        entity.setNoteName(noteName);
        entity.setSex(sex);
        entity.setCreated(created);
        entity.setUpdated(updated);
        entity.setStatus(status);
        entity.setOrgGuid(orgGuid);
        entity.setCreaterID(createrID);
        entity.setIfSync(ifSync);
        entity.setIfRegHx(ifRegHx);
        return entity;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Because I implements Parcelable and Cloneable. If I only implements Parcelable, it's OK.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass complete object as follows.

Create your Model as Parcelable

```
public class Response_GetReEnrolment implements Parcelable
{
    public String app_id;
    public String status;


    protected Response_GetReEnrolment(Parcel in)
    {
        app_id = in.readString();
        status = in.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags)
    {
        dest.writeString(app_id);
        dest.writeString(status);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public static final Creator<Response_GetReEnrolment> CREATOR = new Creator<Response_GetReEnrolment>()
    {
        @Override
        public Response_GetReEnrolment createFromParcel(Parcel in)
        {
            return new Response_GetReEnrolment(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Response_GetReEnrolment[] newArray(int size)
        {
            return new Response_GetReEnrolment[size];
        }
    };
}
```

```
private Response_GetReEnrolment response;

Intent intent = new Intent(activity, Activity_ReEnrollment_Declaration.class);
        intent.putExtra(AppConstants.INTENT_EXTRA_RE_ENROLMENT_RESPONSE, response);

        startActivity(intent);
```

In Second Activity in onCreate

```
response = (Response_GetReEnrolment)getIntent().getExtras().get(AppConstants.INTENT_EXTRA_RE_ENROLMENT_RESPONSE);
```

Comment: Thanks. I know the reason. Because  I implements Parcelable and Cloneable. If I only implements Parcelable, it's OK. Do you know how to solve?

Comment: I have used your model. For me it is working fine. See my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
ContactEntity entity = new ContactEntity();
        entity.setContactID("1");
        entity.setGroupID("1");
        entity.setPhone("2323");
        entity.setName("2323");
        entity.setNoteName("2323");
        entity.setSex(1);
        entity.setCreated(1L);
        entity.setUpdated(1L);
        entity.setStatus(0);
        entity.setOrgGuid("2323");
        entity.setCreaterID("2323");
        entity.setIfSync(0);
        entity.setIfRegHx(0);

        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, Activity_ReEnrollment_Declaration.class);
        intent.putExtra("contact", entity);

        startActivity(intent);
```

In Second Activity

```
ContactEntity entity = (ContactEntity)getIntent().getExtras().get("contact");
entity.getContactID();
```

Comment: Please try to add "intent.putExtra("string", true) "and get it in another Activity.

Comment: Yup. It is working fine. Getting the data using boolean string = (boolean) getIntent().getExtras().get("string"); Can you elaborate your issue.

Comment: Please to see my new answer.

Comment: Did you try with the solution I have posted. Just remove bundle. Add it to putExtra directly and get it from getExtras().get() and cast it.

Comment: yes, I tried. But the result is same.

Answer (score 0):

I post my Intent in here.

```
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putParcelable("contact",contactEntity);
                Intent intent = new Intent(AppointmentActivity.this,ReceiptBillForOnlineActivity.class);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                intent.putExtra("isAppointment",true);
                startActivity(intent);
```

In another Activity, I want to get the Extras.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    isAppointment = intent.getBooleanExtra("isAppointment",false);
    currentContact = intent.getParcelableExtra("contact");
```

getParcelableExtra is successful, but getBooleanExtra is failed or throw Exception.